# sendEmail dh key too small

Tags: centos, smtp, logjam

We use sendEmail to interface to customers mail server and send e-mails out of our software.  currently I am attempting to authenticate send email against an ATT e-mail account.  I keep getting the error below.  I have found some mention on how to fix it on sendmail, but I have had no luck on finding how to fix it with sendEmail.

```
Nov 18 12:51:06 customer sendEmail[32118]: Message input complete.
Nov 18 12:51:06 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => Connecting to websitesmail.att.com:587
Nov 18 12:51:07 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => My IP address is: 192.168.254.4
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => evalSMTPresponse() - Found SMTP success code: 220
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: SUCCESS => Received:     220 mail162c45.carrierzone.com ESMTP Bigfoot 1.0; Wed, 18 Nov 2015 18:51:06 +0000
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: INFO => Sending:     EHLO customer
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => evalSMTPresponse() - Found SMTP success code: 250
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: SUCCESS => Received:     250-mail162c45.carrierzone.com Hello [23.102.181.228], pleased to meet you, 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES, 250-8BITMIME, 250-SIZE 52428800, 250-DSN, 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5, 250-STARTTLS, 250-DELIVERBY, 250 HELP
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => The remote SMTP server supports TLS :)
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => Starting TLS
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: INFO => Sending:     STARTTLS
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: DEBUG => evalSMTPresponse() - Found SMTP success code: 220
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: SUCCESS => Received:     220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
Nov 18 12:51:08 customer sendEmail[32118]: ERROR => TLS setup failed: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown errorerror:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
```

Below is the website for the sendEmail program

http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/#comments

Any help would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Last release in 2009? Seriously? Get rid of it. If the author can't be bothered to keep it secure, you have no hope.

Comment: while I do not disagree, it is curious because services like gmail and office 365 do not cause us problems.  but ISP based e-mail services do.

Comment: They will in future, when they finally get around to upgrading their security to modern standards (and it's quite surprising that they haven't already).

Comment: I think you should try and edit sendEmail using recommendations from [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68952/17042)